# How does recursion work in google sheets defined functions?

Tags: google-sheets, recursion, google-sheets-formula, named-function

Here is an example given by google of a [Named function using recursion](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534)

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ", str)), str, REVERSE_WORDS(RIGHT(str, LEN(str)-FIND(" ", str)))&" "&LEFT(str, FIND(" ",str)-1))
```

This function will take "1 2 3 4" and the final output will be "4 3 2 1" but I am trying to understand exactly why this is occurring specifically by taking it step by step and this is what I have so far:

```
Imaginary Debugging  
Step 1
iserror false
Step 2
REVERSE_WORDS( "2 3 4" )
Step 3
iserror false
Step 4
REVERSE_WORDS( "3 4" )
Step 5
iserror false
Step 6
REVERSE_WORDS( "4" )
Step 7?
iserror true so return 4?
Step 8?
???
```

I don't understand exactly how the final output becomes "4 3 2 1" can someone please write out the remaining steps or correct them for me to visualize since I can't debug/evaluate functions in google sheets. I understand `&" "&LEFT(str, FIND(" ",str)-1))` will output 1 then 2 then 3 and then not trigger the forth time because of the iserror but it seems like the output should be "4 1 2 3" or just "4 1" or "4 3".

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is a programming strategy, where a function calls itself. If a function is made to call itself, it can call itself indefinitely. For recursion to return a valid value, the exit strategy should be inside the function itself.

> IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ", str)), str, REVERSE_WORDS(RIGHT(str, LEN(str)-FIND(" ", str)))&" "&LEFT(str, FIND(" ",str)-1))

Here, the exit strategy is provided `ISERROR`. During each recursion, the function checks, if `FIND()` throws a error, if it throws a error, the function returns the `str`ing, else it keeps calling itself. Whenever it calls itself, it leaves a value.

`REVERSE_WORDS()&" "&LEFT(str, FIND(" ",str)-1))`

Here, it leaves `LEFT(str, number of characters)` on each call. The number of characters is determined by finding the first space in the string. In the case of

```
1 2 3 4
```

```
Imaginary Debugging  
Step 1
iserror false
Return REVERSE_WORDS( "2 3 4" )& " 1"
Step 2
REVERSE_WORDS( "2 3 4" )
iserror false
Return REVERSE_WORDS( "3 4" )& " 2"
Step 3
REVERSE_WORDS( "3 4")
iserror false
Return REVERSE_WORDS( "4" )& " 3"
Step 4
REVERSE_WORDS( "4" )
iserror true so 
Return "4"
```

Note that the first return is the real return or the return we receive from calling `REVERSE_WORDS( "1 2 3 4" )`. That return is

```
REVERSE_WORDS( "2 3 4" )& " 1"
```

The `REVERSE_WORDS( "2 3 4" )` call in that first return returns:

```
REVERSE_WORDS( "3 4" )& " 2"
```

Combined, the first return can be written as,

```
REVERSE_WORDS( "3 4" )& " 2"& " 1"
```

If we keep substituting(recursing), we get,

```
"4"&" 3"&" 2"&" 1"
```

which is

```
4 3 2 1
```

---

- Why isn't it `1 2 3 4`?

Because of the order of operation. If we change

```
REVERSE_WORDS()&" "&LEFT()
```

to

```
LEFT()&" "&REVERSE_WORDS()
```

We'll get `1 2 3 4`

Answer (score 1):

```
#1 =IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ", str)), str, 
#2 REVERSE_WORDS(RIGHT(str, LEN(str)-FIND(" ", str)))
#3 &" "&
#4 LEFT(str, FIND(" ",str)-1))
```

---

#1 If there is no space in the input, return the input.

#4 Extract the first element from the input and place it at the end of the output

#2 Extract the string without the first element from the input and recur

#3 Concat the return value of recursion (#2) and the first element (#4) with a space

---

**1st level:**

| Step | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Input | 1 2 3 4 |
| #1 | False |
| #4 | 1 |
| #2 | REVERSE_WORDS("2 3 4") |
| #3 | `Return of 2nd level` 1 |

**2nd level:**

| Step | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Input | 2 3 4 |
| #1 | False |
| #4 | 2 |
| #2 | REVERSE_WORDS("3 4") |
| #3 | `Return of 3rd level` 2 |

**3rd level:**

| Step | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Input | 3 4 |
| #1 | False |
| #4 | 3 |
| #2 | REVERSE_WORDS("4") |
| #3 | `Return of 4th level` 3 |

**4th level:**

| Step | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Input | 4 |
| #1 | TRUE |
| #4 | 4 |
| #2 |  |
| #3 | 4 |

---

**Finally, the return values are concatted as follows:**

| Level | Return |
| --- | --- |
| 4th | 4 |
| 3rd | 4 3 |
| 2nd | 4 3 2 |
| 1st | 4 3 2 1 |